# Magento currency switching issue

Tags: magento-1.9, currency, switcher

My website saree.com is built on magento. Follow this steps and you will notice the issue.
1. Login to account
2. Add product to cart
3. Logout
4. Change Currency
5. Login to account
6. Check product in cart.

Only currency gets changed but price remains the same. Any clue ?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To setup multiple currency in any Magento Website is two step process.

1. **System->General->Currency Setup->** Add Allowed Currencies (These Settings are based on stores & websites)
2. **System->Manage Currency->Rates**->import & save currency rates.

Chek if these two steps are followed for currency set up.

Comment: I have a single store view and multiple currency enabled. Is it a wrong configuration ?

Comment: No, its correct single store view can have multiple currency.

Comment: If issue is still there  then this issue is because of price formatting in templates file.

Comment: Possible, I have hacked paypal to accept multi currency. Thanks for help.